# New to auto layout, views not displaying as configured in IB

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

Ive been going nuts over this for days and I've tried everything I know so far about auto layout but can't get past this.  I have a stack of buttons and a label. The label is at the top and 5 buttons below it. Each View is a rectangle that is 8 points from either end of the superview in width. The label is 134 points in height and each button below it is slightly smaller(though the screen shot shows 83 in height for each as I was testing something and forgot to change it(I can re-post the image if need be with the decrementing heights)), the bottom most button being 65 points in height. That is all. Seems like a simple, straightforward design right? Well, having studied the basics of auto layout for the last 2 weeks and finding the 'Ray Wenderlich' tutorials a great help, I've tried everything I could to get this to simulate correctly but it just doesn't! I set the constraints for each view, trailing, leading, bottom, top, height, width everything as correct as I can fathom but this is what happens:

On the 4s: the label at the top becomes a thin line

On the 6 plus: the label is much bigger than it should be

I'm limited as to how and how many images I can post as I am a new member.

Interface Builder:

[image: IB SCREENSHOT]

iPhone 4s:

[image: 4s SIMULATOR]

Comment: Is there an explicit height constraint on the label itself?

Comment: do not give height/width constraint for an element unless needed. Always give the top,bottom,leading,trailing and let autolayout decide the width and height for that particular element.

Comment: yes, its 134 points. I set it by control dragging on the label which displays the popover menu

Comment: Your view is too tall to fit on a 4s screen. 134 for the label + 83 * 4 for the buttons is already 466.  Adding in the spacing between the views and your height is way more than the 480 height of the screen.

Comment: You're also over constraining your views so the constraints only work for a single height.  If you delete the bottom spacing constraint between the last button and the bottom of the view it should work on the 6 plus.

Comment: @dan  should I be using the 4s size canvas or should I use the universal canvas and set the sizes as you have explained?

Comment: I always use the universal canvas but your views need to either be set up so that they can shrink to fit on a smaller screen or stick them in a scrollview

Comment: I shall go over the design again in IB according to these suggestions and be back. Thank You

Comment: Rather than hard coding the height of the buttons, if you want them to be the same size, define them to be the same height as each other, and then that, combined with all the top/bottom constraints, they'll be laid out to be the same size, regardless of device. And if you want the label to be, say twice the height of the buttons, define that constraint accordingly.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri  could you give me an example as to when you would 'need' to give height/width constraints for an element please..

Comment: Autolayout keeps ruining my design.. Every time I set the layout constraints and do whatever I can to be precise and using the above suggestions, Mr auto layout gives me a bunch of 'expectations'. Why the hell would Mr auto layout expect my design to be anything other than what I want it to be?? This is the most counterintuitive technology I have ever used and is costing me so much time and energy... I'm not allowed to post any more pictures of screenshots and I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: @DannyHuseyin - Just give us links to images and we can incorporate them in the question. And don't give up on auto layout, as we've all been there once, just wanting to chuck it out the window the first time we did anything complicated. But once you get your arms around it, it really is a powerful (if not always intuitive) way to define dynamically sized views which is our new reality now that devices are different sizes and we have split-screen features on iPads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you talk about precisely how many points each of the buttons were to be, but you didn't describe how you wanted it to behave when the device wasn't tall enough for that representation (e.g. on iPhone 4s).

Bottom line, in addition to the standard leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints, I might suggest that you consider defining the heights of the various labels/buttons relative to each other. For example, consider the following constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    // leading constraints

    pinkLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
    button1.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
    button2.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
    button3.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
    button4.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),

    // trailing constraints

    view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(pinkLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button2.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button3.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button4.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),

    // vertical spacing constraints

    pinkLabel.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
    button1.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(pinkLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
    button2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
    button3.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button2.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
    button4.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button3.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
    view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button4.bottomAnchor, constant: 83),

    // now set relative height

    pinkLabel.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.5),
    button2.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.heightAnchor),
    button3.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.heightAnchor),
    button4.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button1.heightAnchor)
])
```

(By the way, I'm showing these programmatically because it's the easiest way to unambiguously articulate all the constraints, but you can set these up in IB or implement in Objective-C, too. Implement it anyway you want, but these are example constraints.)

That will result in, on three different devices:

[image]

Clearly, you can change those constraints to whatever you want, but this illustrates one approach. Bottom line, just add standard leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints and then define the heights of the various labels/buttons relative to each other.

In your question, you show us what you did *not* want it to look like on the smaller screen, but never articulated what it *should* look like. If you clarify how you want it to appear on different sized screens, then we can probably help further.

Comment: thank you so much,. Seems I need to learn and understand what multipliers are and how to use them to define views relative to each other. I have to learn this quick! If there are any tutorials you could recommend I'd be grateful but I'll see how I can get on myself. I'll be back..

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials (other than the relevant WWDC videos), but the underlying idea is simple: You can define a constraint to be either equal to another constraint (e.g. button2 is the same height as button1), a multiple of another constraint (e.g. label is 1.5 times the height of button1), the other constraint plus some constant (e.g. the top of the label is the top of the superview plus 20), or you can even do a combination (e.g. some view's height can be defined to be 50 + two times another view's height). So above, I just defined the label to be one and a half the button's height.

Comment: so it's as if the design layout in IB is not necessarily what it will look like on the device screen. The way it will look on the device screen is defined by the constraints and setting of each constraints properties. So it's more about thinking how each element relates to the next when running on different device sizes rather than precise placement/sizing of elements as if they are meant for a single sized screen? So what are the list of 'expectations' on the left of the editor actually referring to? What does Xcode mean by 'expect' so and so y/x/height/width etc..?

Comment: Yes, in IB you generally define views relative to other views. You can, though, in IB, ask it to show you your constraints using "simulated metrics" for different devices (this is found on the "attributes inspector" for the scene), so you get a decent sense of how it would appear on various devices right in IB. But you generally want to minimize how often you "hard code" various sizes. Re "expectations", I'm not sure what you mean, so perhaps post a new question on this. But if you're using an old version of Xcode, note that the autolayout handling in IB is much better now.

Comment: Rob can you help me please :(  I’ve wasted over a week on this and I’ve failed miserably to understand what is going on and I’m at the the end of my tether. All I want is for my app to look like this  http://www.mediafire.com/download/np4aqpulrcpnfkp/Screen_Shot_2016-03-13_at_19.15.07.png  on all iPhone portrait screen sizes. Thats all. I've tried all I can and read/watched every tutorial on the subject of multipliers and auto/adaptive Layout but I just can't get it to work and my vision has gone fuzzy with frustration.. Can I ask how its done using IB please.. I'd be so grateful

Comment: @DannyHuseyin - This is equally frustrating for us because you show us what you want it to look like at one particular size, but don't tell us how you want the controls to change for different screen resizes. Do they all resize proportionally? If so, you define the heights as multiples of each other. In your screen snapshot, label is 162pt tall, and the buttons are 108, 93, 76, 58, and 29pt tall, respectively. Then define button 1 height as 108.0/162.0 of label height. Button 2 height as 93.0/162.0 of label. Etc. But if they don't change proportionally, then what behavior do you want?!?

Comment: Yes I need the buttons and the label to resize proportionally for each screen resize so the app looks the same across all devices (portrait). When you say to 'define the heights as multiples of each other' and 'define button 1 height as 108.0/162.0 of label etc..' I am lost as to what you mean by this because I do not understand the method of implementation required to enable the views to resize proportionally for each device. If I set all the views to various heights on the canvas, what must I then do further to this to enable the views to resize correctly? Sorry If I sound confused..

Comment: @DannyHuseyin - My answer above demonstrates what I mean, but perhaps this video will serve as a practical demonstration of the process. I go through the process relatively quickly, but hopefully this illustrates the idea: Don't use any "constant" height constraints, but rather define the heights relative to each other: http://youtu.be/XCCGIcloQBI. And here is a sample project where the storyboard has these sorts of constraints: https://github.com/robertmryan/DynamicButtonHeightDemo

Comment: :)))))) Thank You Thank You Thank You Thank You!!

Comment: Can I just ask a few questions to clear a few things up please? I am working with xib files.. I get height constraints when I click 'suggested constraints' although I cleared them.
At 1:15, you control drag to create a constraint, how did you change the popover display?
When I set the bottom space to container constraint to 20, the label gets bigger but the bottom button stayed the same size?
Why do I have to update frames every time I toggle between the simulated metrics so the canvas displays correctly?
I noticed you had the red errors on your IB.. what would you have done to correct those?

Comment: @DannyHuseyin - This works in NIB, too. When you control-drag and get popover, you can press 'option' key and toggle the choices. In terms of IB automatically resizing the frames, yes, it seems unproductive when tweaking constraints, but when adding a bunch of constraints at the start, it would be annoying to have an incomplete set of constraints applied because until you're done, very weird things could happen. The red error in IB was just that the label had lingering fixed height constraint, and when I removed that, error went away.

Comment: @Rob: Can we set UIButton's font according to its height or width?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the label with fixed height in a vertical stack view with another vertical stack view and put all the buttons in the inner vertical stack view and set the `Distribution: Fill Equally` as well as a spacing of your choosing. This will show the most accurate on all phones. Make sure the outer stack view's constraints are set. No need to set the inner stack with any constraints and everything will fall in place.

Answer (score 0):

**Set button bottom constraints low priority like**

[image]